# Meteor Accounts on Login callback not working

Tags: meteor

I have this code in a file on the client. When I login nothing gets logged out. I found out the onLogin callback is now available on the client. It should work.

```
Accounts.onLogin ->
  console.log 'sdfdsfsd'
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it works for me. What version of meteor are you using?

Comment: Meteor 1.1.0.2. I cannot update to 1.2 until the iOS DDP package I am using can handle web socket compression.